Dealing with large ipynb files
My notebook is too large to post on github. Is there a way of reduce the size of the file or other way to post without clear outputs of it? I need to show the graphs on the file
i've tried to compact the file with ipynbcompress library, but doesnt work

How did you try to compact it? I'm not a Jupyter expert, but I imagine people will want the specifics. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips. You can [edit] to add details / clarify.

I've not used Jupyter myself, but I would imagine you can probably import from other files, right?
